# System.Data.DataTable event raised on RejectChanges

Tags: c#, system.data.datatable

I have a huge DataTable instance bound to a GUI, next to the DataTable there lays a specialized object (let's call it ValuesIndex)implementing fast access to DataTable content. The problem is I need to keep ValuesIndex synchronized with the current state of the DataTable. 
When there are some values in DataTable which have not been accepted yet - I need to keep them in ValuesIndex. I also need to react properly to RejectChanges - so the whole ValuesIndex returns to its previous state.

**Is there a possibility to set up event handlers for DataTable instance so the RejectChanges is catched?**
I tried to achieve that with usage of RowChanged event, but I cannot rely on that. If I delete a row from a table and then reject the changes, the RowChanged event is not called for some reason.

**UPDATE:**
Turns out that I just deleted the rows the wrong way, instead of calling *DataRow.Delete()* I used DataTable.Rows.Remove. RowChanging event is fired both on AcceptChanges and RejectChanges

Comment: Why do you add another layer that needs to be maintained and synchronized at all? The `DataTable` provides already access to it's content and provides events to handle changes. So what is the benefit of your class if it  makes all more complicated?

Comment: I need to be able to quickly find row or rows which for column x carry value y. Iterating through the table is not an option.

Comment: However, but the problem is not clear. Why don't you hold the `DataTable` as private property in your class and expose your own methods, properties and events? If the table can not be modified without  your methods you have full control over your calculations.